# got "error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix" in xml file

Tags: xml, parsing, prefix

I understand others have asked this but I have followed their instructions but still get the same error message. Here is the xml file for tweened animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set>
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
<alpha
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="2500">        
</alpha>

</set>
```

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Moses

Answer (score 3):

You have an issue at the  tag. You have closed the `<Set>` tag without including `xmlns:` part of the code

```
<set**>**
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
```

Comment: @user1124591: If the answer helped you, please upvote it (click the up-pointing triangle above the vote count) and then "accept" it (click the check-mark).

Answer (score 1):

Your XML is syntactically invalid.  Maybe you meant something like this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
<alpha
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="2500">        
</alpha>

</set>
```